# Session-based login not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I have been developing a PHP and mysqli based social network as a side project. All has been going well up till this point. Everyone can register and I am using the crypt function to store passwords.

I am using an `if` and `else` statement with the `password_verify` function where I set `$_SESSION` variables and cookies in order to login. Again this works and once logged in the system redirects me to my user profile as it should.

However my site-top.php file does not work as it should; what should happen is that the dynamic login link buttons should change from the login and register buttons to the logout, profile and notification buttons.

Also the add as friend button and block button are disabled on my profile (as it should as I don't want to block or friend myself) but they are also disabled when I visit another's profile which it should not.

Here is the code for my site top for the time being. I have also got a check-login-status file should you wish me to post the code for that or any others:

```
<?php
// It is important for any file that includes this file, to have
// check_login_status.php included at its very top.
$envelope = '<img src="assets/note_dead.png" width="33" height="33" alt="Notes" title="This envelope is for logged in members">';
$loginLink = '<li><a class="tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="Register an Account" href="signup.php">Register</a></li>
              <li><a class="tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="Login" href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
if($user_ok == true) {
    $sql = "SELECT notescheck FROM users WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $notescheck = $row[0];
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE username='$log_username' AND date_time > '$notescheck' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows == 0) {
        $envelope = '<a href="#" title="Your Notifications & Friend Requests"><img src="assets/note_still.png" width="33" height="33" alt="Notes"></a>';
    } else {
        $envelope = '<a href="#" title="You have new Notifications"><img src="assets/note_flash.gif" width="33" height="33" alt="Notes"></a>';
    }
    $loginLink = '<li><a class="tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="Logout" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li><li><a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'">'.$log_username.'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

OK this is my check-login-status.php script for all that wanted it...

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db_conx.php");
// Files that inculde this file at the very top would NOT require 
// connection to database or session_start(), be careful.
// Initialize some vars
$user_ok = false;
$log_id = "";
$log_username = "";
$log_password = "";
// User Verify function
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    } else if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
        $_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
        $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
        $_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);
        $log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
        // Verify the user
        $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
        if($user_ok == true){
        // Update their lastlogin datetime field
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$log_id' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: There's code missing: how is `$user_ok` set?

Comment: *does not work as it should*, what does not work and how should it work? Please explain.

Comment: Hi Mouser,I am using a check login status script for that! do you want me to provide the code for that?

Comment: Hi Mohammad it's the site-top.php file that is now working as it should! The dynamic buttons are not changing as I login!

Comment: Yes, because it looks like your if isn't getting executed.

Comment: Aside: it's not clear whether you have escaped `$log_username` and other items of user input, so as to avoid SQL injection. Even if you have, you should switch to parameterisation/binding, rather than relying on string concatenation - it is safer.

Comment: @halfer Thabk you for that Will use the '@' Device from now on!

Comment: @Mouser Thank you buddy I have added the check user log code!

Comment: We can't run this code, you need to provide some debug information. What is `$user_ok` returning. `var_dump` it onto your page and come back with the result.